# What is the equivalent of function readlink in linux kernel space?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver, readlink

I have some program, that opened a few files. I got the pid of this process. I can get the file name of the file, that has been opened by this process using this command:

```
readlink /proc/3826/fd/10
```

This gives me the full path to file.
How can I do the same in kernel user space? I didn't find the way to use readlink in kernel space.

Comment: @ringø Will that work for `/proc` -- these aren't real symlinks.

Comment: it will work because it's a fs, but it does not make sense to do it this way. what op wants to do is to translate the fd to file pointer -> dentry and perform a reverse full path lookup on that. doing readlink on procfs will end up doing the same thing, except with a ton of other intermediate work for no reason (in this case). that said, given the quality of the question i have to ask for justification of the entire business.

Comment: @employeeofthemonth: In fact it won't work. readlink on the /proc/*/fd/* links gives the path it was opened by which might not exist anymore, but opening the file from /proc/*/fd/* links with open() works.

Comment: Ok, so you want to do readlink() in /proc to get the file name. Yes, you can invoke the readlink operation from the /proc filesystem node to do this, and that does get the file name it was opened by. However, this does not do what you think it does. 
I've played with this stuff long ago. Those links in /proc do different things when you call readlink() and followlink(). If you don't post what you are trying to do nobody can answer the question.

Comment: if you want to nitpick, it's not the path it was opened with but the current location of the name (possibly appended with "(deleted)" if, well, the name got unlinked). either way, you can do readlink on it and that's presumably what Barmar asked. i also asked what this is for, as it is most likely not what you want to do in the first place. i don't see how the fact that opening the file through the fd entry duplicates the file pointer plays any role here.